# How to get a QR reader to recognize your generated QR Code?

Tags: javascript, android, html, qr-code

I want to make an app that generates unique QR codes for users. But I also need a QR reader to recognize them.

So, for example, I want a user to create an account and click a button to generate a QR Code. Then they can put this generated QR Code where ever they want and when people scan this QR Code, their account pops up.

Is there a way to get any QR reader to recognize my generated QR codes?

Ill be using JavaScript, HTML etc.

Comment: **How to get a QR reader to recognize your generated QR code?** easy, generate valid QR code

Comment: What code are you using to generate a QR Code?  Can you show us an example of the QR Codes you are generating?

Comment: i have obviously got confused along the way here. I have just been using an online code generator and i was sure my QR scanner wasn't able to scan it last week, but now it works. Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QR Code scanning/generating there is library available to android : 
[Zxing Library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

and you can provide any button in html that can call android code as mentioned by google [Html-To-Android call](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)